# Adding external ram to 2014 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

I'm new to macs so please bear with me if I say something dumb.

I recently switched over to Mac, and purchased a new MacBook Pro, but found that the computer did not have enough ram for everything I am doing (large photoshop files etc.) I was wondering if there is any way that I could get external ram or some type of upgrade for my computer.

Essentially, can I get an external ram drive, or should I go back and upgrade the computer itself?

Comment: Retina or non-Retina MacBook Pro? If it's one of the Retina models, there's no way to upgrade the internal RAM.

Comment: It is retina, but what about any external solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The internal RAM is soldered to the motherboard (i.e. totally user-untouchable), but for external RAM, you're welcome to [check out this article](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-create-a-4gbs-ram-disk-in-mac-os-x/) at your own risk.

UPDATE: After having [done some research,](http://www.pcworld.com/article/260918/how_to_supercharge_your_pc_with_a_ram_disk.html) apparently RAM disks are exactly the opposite of what I'd thought. They actually turn a segment of your RAM into hard drive space. It still promises massive speed boosts, though, so you should give it a try if you're up for it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but no, you can't upgrade.

Comment: The pre-edit instructions you listed were for the non-Retina MBP... :)

Comment: @user24601 yea, that's non upgradable.